# Images from UICollectionView changes to wrong images while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I found some similar questions but none of them worked for me. I have a UICollectionView acting as a feed with posts that can contain images. I fetch all the information (images included) from Firebase and when refreshing or scrolling up/down the collection, images change from one cell to another. I know this is for downloading the image & delays but I'm using SDWebImage already and tried prepareForReuse but none of this worked. Here's some code:

```
class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController { 
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
              let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: homeImageTextCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeImageTextCell
              cell.delegate = self

              //Here I have the information with the URL image downloaded from FB
              cell.viewModel = PostViewModel(post: posts[indexPath.row])

              return cell
        }
}
```

The HomeImageTextCell is a UICollectionViewCell with a collectionView inside to display the images, posts can have more than one to display. Inside this cell:

```
class HomeImageTextCell: UICollectionViewCell {

private let collectionView: UICollectionView = { ... }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier!, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
        cell.viewModel = PostImageViewModel(imageString: imagesToDisplay[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

}
```

And finally, the ImageCollectionViewCell just has an image to display the image fetched from Firebase. This cell is the one that gets messy:

```
class ImageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var viewModel: PostImageViewModel? {
        didSet {
            configure()
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Properties
    
    lazy var postImageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.postImageView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(postImageView)
        postImageView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, right: rightAnchor)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure() {
        guard let viewModel = viewModel else { return }
        postImageView.sd_setImage(with: viewModel.imageToDisplay, placeholderImage: UIImage())
       
    }
}
```

Comment: try `override func prepareForReuse() {  super.prepareForReuse() self.postImageView.iimage = nil }`

Comment: Thanks for answer, still loading images in random order setting up image to nil

Comment: Do you have collection view inside collection view cell?

Comment: Yes! Could this be an error for displaying wrong images?

Comment: That should be debug. I think I have to check full code to know that better

Comment: Removing the collectionView inside the cell and putting the image on the first cell solved the problem with this approach. The thing is posts could have more than 1 image associated so I'll need to think of another approach depending on how many images needs to be displayed (declaring as many UIImages as images post has, and also setting up constraints...) seems tedious :o

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245029/discussion-between-bhavin-bhadani-and-unbound).

Answer (score 0):

add `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before returning cell.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier!, for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.viewModel = PostImageViewModel(imageString: imagesToDisplay[indexPath.row])
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: After aplying the changes I see cells are still loading up in random orders

Comment: @Unbound  in your cellForItemAt method -- set cell.imageview.image = nil
and then load your image

Comment: Same issue, still not working with this approach

Answer (score 0):

try  `postImageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()` in your `prepareForReuse()`

Comment: I tried but still not displaying correct images sometimes!

Comment: Then place a default image in your assets and in prepareForReuse() set that default image postImageView.image = UIImage(named: "default_image"), This will first change image to default image and then set new image